# Is there a way of handling the GotFocus event on all text boxes in all views by convention?

Tags: .net, wpf, conventions, caliburn.micro

We are writing a WPF based application that is usually used on a touchscreen tablet. We are designing the UI to avoid text input, but there times when that can't be avoided. For those times we want to control when and what type of keyboard is popped up for input.

We can create a base custom control to add the appropriate event handler, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this by convention instead.

We are using CaliburnMicro for our MVVM framework and as it supports convention customization I started looking into `ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<TextBox>(null, null, "GotFocus")` but calling that will replace any existing conventions. I thought about something like:

```
var textboxConvention = ConventionManager.GetElementConvention(typeof(TextBox));
var oldBinding = textboxConvention.ApplyBinding;
textboxConvention.ApplyBinding = 
    (viewModelType, path, property, element, convention) =>
        {
           element.GotFocus += ((o, args) => ShowKeyboard((TextBox)o));
           element.LostFocus += ((o, args) => HideKeyboard((TextBox)o));
           return oldBinding(viewModelType, path, property, element, convention);
         };
```

...but I suspect I've gone down the wrong path here.

Is there a better way to chain bindings? Is there a better way to handling the focus events/bringing up the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before. You can create an [attached behavior](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx) that listens for PreviewGotKeyboardFocus on the element in question causing the OnScreenKeyboard to display. Then create a style that applies the attached behavior to those controls. In my project, we also had different Keyboards for different input types (for example text versus numeric). The attached behavior set a KeyboardType for its property. Based on the KeyboardType, I would display the appropriate keyboard.

If you need further assistance let me know.

Comment: Thanks that worked really well. I'm no dealing with the issue of switching from one control to another, got focus on the new control fires before the lost focus on the old. I'll try working it out with streams in RX. BTW I'd be interested what keyboard you use, we're trying a few

Comment: Yes I had to handle that situation as well...basically the trick I did was I stored what the Current focused element was on the PreviewGotFocused event. When a new GotFocused event was received, I would compare with the Current element and if different deregister the lost focus event on the old element. I think we used a custom Keyboard but later found WPFKB on codeplex that has a lot of it built in.

Answer (score 1):

I think GotFocus is a bubbling event so can you add a handler to the window or page then capture any GotFocus events that bubble to the top of your element tree? You can then handle the event as appropriate, or not handle it and allow any other registered handlers to deal with it. I guess the only issue is if the TextBox handles and swallows the event, and off the top of my head I'm not sure about that.

HTH,

Bart